# How to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1!+2!+\cdots+n!}{(2n)!}$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Show that this series converges:
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1!+2!+\cdots+n!}{(2n)!}$$

My solution: this series converges since
$$1!+2!+\cdots+n!\le n!+n!+\cdots+n!=n\cdot n!$$
and
since
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n\cdot n!}{(2n)!}$$ is convergent because
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{(n+1)\cdot(n+1)!}{(2(n+1))!}\cdot\dfrac{(2n)!}{(n\cdot n!}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{n+1}{2(2n+1)n}=0.$$

My question: are there other methods to solve this problem? Such as if we let $$a_{n}=\dfrac{1!+2!+\cdots+n!}{(2n)!},$$ then can we prove $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}<1?$$
Thank you very much!

Comment: When $n \ge 3, 2n \ge n+3$, we have
$$\frac{n\cdot n!}{2n!} < \frac{(n+1)!}{2n!} \le \frac{(n+1)!}{(n+3)!} = \frac{1}{(n+2)(n+3)} = \frac{1}{n+2}-\frac{1}{n+3}$$ This implies for all $N \ge 3$,

$$\sum_{n=3}^N\frac{1!+\cdots+n!}{2n!} \le \sum_{n=3}^N\left(\frac{1}{n+2}-\frac{1}{n+3}\right) \le \frac15$$

Comment: @achillehui,Hello, if we let $a_{n}=\dfrac{1!+2!+\cdots+n!}{(2n)!}$,then we can prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}<1?$

Comment: Your solution is correct, @nanchangjian

Comment: @DonAntonio,so I want see other methods?

Answer (score 8):

Since $(2n)!=(n!)^2\dbinom{2n}{n}>(n!)^2$, then
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1!+\dots+n!}{(2n)!}<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n\cdot n!}{(n!)^2}
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n-1)!}=e<\infty.$$

Comment: Nice idea and methods! Thank you +1

Answer (score 0):

If you stick to

$$a_n={1!+2!+\cdots+n!\over(2n)!}$$

then

$$\begin{align}
\left|{a_{n+1}\over a_n}\right|&={(2n)!\over(2n+2)!}\left({1!+2!+\cdots+n!+(n+1)!\over1!+2!+\cdots+n!}\right)\\
&={1\over2(n+1)(2n+1)}\left(1+{(n+1)!\over1!+2!+\cdots+n!} \right)\\
&={1\over2(2n+1)}\left({1\over n+1}+{n!\over1!+2!+\cdots+n!}\right)\\
&\le{1\over2(2n+1)}\left({1\over n+1}+1\right)\\
&\le{1\over2n+1}
\end{align}$$

so $|a_{n+1}/a_n|\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.